# Pandas - Compare Columns and return False when they are not matching and also when one of the column says "Column not found"

Tags: python, pandas

I am comparing two columns using Pandas.

```
Pre_Out_df[res_name] = Pre_Out_df[plain_col] == Pre_Out_df[b_col]
```

The above code returns false.

But I want the code to return false when any one of the value between Plain_col and b_col says"Column Not Found".

I want to return false on the last case in the df below,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this condition instead, where it checks if `plain_col` and `res_name` are same `AND` if `res_name` is `Not Found`. Ideally we need to check if either of them are `Not Found` but since we have already checked if they are same or not, either one of them is checked (`res_name` in this case).

`((df['res_name'] == df['plain_col']) & (df['res_name'] != 'Not Found'))`

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'res_name': [1,2,'Not Found'],
    'plain_col': [1,2,'Not Found']
})
```

Output for `df`:

```
    res_name    plain_col
0   1           1
1   2           2
2   Not Found   Not Found
```

Then  below code:

```
((df['res_name'] == df['plain_col']) & (df['res_name'] != 'Not Found'))
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: how would this work when plain_col is 'Not Found' and b_col is 'Not Found'

Comment: It would return `TRUE` for first condition and `FALSE` for second. (`TRUE` & `False`) would be `FALSE`. This is how it is in the example as well. @Sid29

Comment: I am struggling to understand res_name being in multiple places. I am looking to have b_col and plain_col in the df and the output column being res_name

Comment: Right now I am not storing the output back to df. The code returns a series that can be put into the df in any column you want.

Comment: Ideally we need to check if either of them are Not Found but since we have already checked if they are same or not, either one of them is checked (res_name in this case). - The Point I was missing, Thank you :)

Comment: Glad, I could help. @Sid29

Answer (score 1):

Replace that columns to `NaN`

```
Pre_Out_df=Pre_Out_df.replace({'Employee Not found',np.nan})

Pre_Out_df[res_name] = Pre_Out_df[plain_col] == Pre_Out_df[b_col]
```

Since

```
np.nan==np.nan
Out[66]: False
```